# URL prettification with arbitrary number of "subdirectories"

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, hierarchy, friendly-url

I'm working on my first site which lives on top of a PHP/Apache stack.

My site has a logical menu structured like this:

```
+AAA Entry
  -AAB Entry
    -AABA Subentry
    -AABB Subentry
  -AAC Entry
    -AACA Subentry
      -AACAA Subentry
      -AACAB Subentry
    -AACB Subentry
  -AAD Entry

+BBB Entry
  -BBC Entry
    -BBCA Subentry
    etc.
+CCC Entry
+DDD Entry
```

My goal is to have valid URLs like these:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/aaa/aab/aaba
http://www.mydomain.com/aaa/aac/aaca/aacaa
http://www.mydomain.com/aaa/aac/aacb
http://www.mydomain.com/aaa/aad

http://www.mydomain.com/bbb
http://www.mydomain.com/bbb/bbc
http://www.mydomain.com/bbb/bbc/bbca

http://www.mydomain.com/ccc
```

---

I've read about `mod_rewrite`'s `RewriteRule` and `RewriteCond` but I'm unsure as to which method to use in terms of maintainability. What if I decide to add another level to `AACAA`, for example? Will I have to mess with `mod_rewrite` over and over again?

Is it more appropriate to redirect everything to `index.php` and parse `REQUEST_URI` manually?
How is this done by professionals?

Comment: This is "done by professionals" by using a [PHP framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/). You shouldn't be rolling your own except as an educational exercise.

Comment: Yep, I'm trying to write my own CMS in hopes of learning PHP and coding for the web in general. This will never be in a production environment. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's far easier to forward all URLs to your controller script, and do your routing in PHP:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* my_script.php [L]
```

The directs all requests for files which do not exist through `my_script.php`. From there, you can examine the request URI, explode it into segments delimited by forward slashes, and route to the correct file.

Comment: That's the only solution I came to myself after thinking about it for a bit. I'll wait a bit for more responses, though before marking this as answered. Thanks!

Comment: +1. Is there a reason why there's no additional `RewriteCond` for `-d` and `-l` ?

Comment: @gore `-l` is redundant (`-f` covers symlinks) and I never want to serve directory contents so no `-d`.